# Why two strings may compare as equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on string comparision with `=` and `LIKE` and I found this in the [documentation](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) :

> Depending on the collating sequence, two strings may compare as equal
>   even if they are of different lengths or contain different sequences
>   of characters. When the operations MAX, MIN, DISTINCT, references to a
>   grouping column, and the UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT operators refer
>   to character strings, the specific value selected by these operations
>   from a set of such equal values is implementation-dependent.

Comment: The collation speficies how the characters are considered for many operations. Some collations may specify different ordering. Other collations may consider lower and upper case equal, may discard white spaces, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking for a concrete example? In German, we have the lower-case letter `ß` (length 1). In upper-case, this letter is usually written as `SS` (length 2) instead. Thus, using a case-insensitive Western-European collation, the following SQL

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'ß' = 'SS' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
```

will output `Yes`, even though the strings have different lengths.

Comment: . . For me, the answer is more convincing as:  `CASE WHEN N'ß' = N'SS' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: True, but since `ß` is contained even in the default code page of US-English-based systems, I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Collations can be sensitive to different things. Currently, there are Case, Accent, Kana, Width and supplementary character sensitivities. There are also Binary collations as well.

So for a collation that is both Case and Accent insensitive, then the strings `N'ABCDEFG'` and `N'äbçdéfg'` would be seen as the "same" string despite that they share no same literal characters.

Emoticons are another area where characters that are completely different can be seen as the same. For example the below returns 1, despite that one string contains emoticons of a cat and a dragon and the other a cake:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = N'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  THEN 1 END;
```